# Copy lines and execute in terminal window

Tags: cut-copy-paste, buffers, terminal

Edit a python file with `vim adddf.py`, and type `vert term` and `python3`, there are two windows in vim.

```
cat adddf.py
def add_df(df,number):
    import re
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    nrow = df.shape[0]
    ncol = df.shape[1]
    for i in range(0,nrow):
        for j in range(0,ncol):
            new_df.at[i,j] =  df.iloc[i,j] + number
    return new_df
```

I want to copy some lines and execute it in left window, write a function:

```
function! CopyRun(start,stop)
    normal a:start,a:stop y+
    wincmd p
    call feedkeys("\<C-W>\"+")
endfunction
```

When I call it with:

```
call CopyRun(1,9)
```

I get the following output

[image]

1. Nothing executed in python terminal,and nothing in `+` register
2. the previous python function changed into below:

```python
    d:start:stop y+ef add_df(df,number):
        import re
        new_df = pd.DataFrame()
        nrow = df.shape[0]
        ncol = df.shape[1]
        for i in range(0,nrow):
            for j in range(0,ncol):
                new_df.at[i,j] =  df.iloc[i,j] + number
        return new_df
```

3. in bottom left, it says: `emmet#anchorizeURL(0)`

After following the answer from `Maxim Kim` in my `.vimrc`.
[image]

I get a new issue :

```
exe "normal! " . a:start . "," . a:stop . "y+"
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check if your vim supports `+` register, `:version` output should include `+clipboard`. I would suggest to use other registers for that.
2. Your `normal` command is wrong. Try smth like:

```
function! CopyRun(start,stop)
    " This would still not work as normal commands do not take range as ex commands...
    exe "normal! " . a:start . "," . a:stop . "y+"
    wincmd p
    call feedkeys("\<C-W>\"+")
endfunction
```

In your case with `normal` you literally run `a` then `:` then `s` etc.
Here `:execute` helps with running a string as a vim command so you can construct your command with string concatenation (or with `printf()`).

It says `emmet...something` because you have used `normal` without `!` mark meaning every letter might be remapped as happened here where your emmet plugin has been triggered.

**PS**

You can also check the source of https://github.com/habamax/vim-sendtoterm plugin.

**PPS**

better use `:yank` command (`:h yank`)

```
function! CopyRun(start,stop)
    exe a:start . "," . a:stop ."yank +"
    wincmd p
    call feedkeys("\<C-W>\"+")
endfunction
```

[image]